# Datatables : Make a parallel request in another table using ServerSide

Tags: mysql, pdo, datatables

EDIT : I found the solution by replacing the SSP class by a customized SSP class I've found here : https://github.com/emran/ssp

I don't know if it's an understandable title, but here is my problem :

I have a DB-table (called projects) that needs to be inserted in a datatable. I've no problem to make a call using ServerSide and get results in the datatable.

But, for each project (each row), there is a project creator (column creator_id in the projects DB-table). What I need to do is to make a request to the creators DB-table in order to get the firstname/lastname of the creator, each time I get a row from the projects DB-table. Is that make sense?

Here is the code I use :

```
$table = 'projects';

$primaryKey = 'project_id';

$columns = array(
    array(
        'db' => 'project_id',
        'dt' => 'DT_RowId',
        'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {
            return $d;
        }
    ),
    array(  'db' => 'creator_id',
            'dt' => 'creator',
            'formatter' => function( $d, $row ) {

                // Here I need to make a call to the creators DB-table and return the $creator_name value

                return $creator_name;

            }
    )
);

// SQL server connection information
$sql_details = array(
    'user' => '',
    'pass' => '',
    'db'   => '',
    'host' => ''
);

require(BASE_DIR.'/lib/dataTables/ssp.class.php');

$result = SSP::simple($_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `formatter` property to make a separate SQL query but it will affect performance greatly by increasing script response time.

Instead you can use the following trick when using `ssp.class.php` with sub-queries instead of table name to use `GROUP BY`, `JOIN`, etc.

```php
<?php

$table = <<<EOT
 (
    SELECT projects.project_id, creators.creator_id, creators.creator_name
     FROM projects
     LEFT JOIN creators ON projects.creator_id=creators.creator_id
 ) t
EOT;

$primaryKey = 'project_id';

$columns = array(
    array(
        'db' => 'project_id',
        'dt' => 'DT_RowId'
    ),
    array(  
        'db' => 'creator_id',
        'dt' => 'creator'
    ),
    array(  
        'db' => 'creator_name',
        'dt' => 'creator_name'
    )
);

// SQL server connection information
$sql_details = array(
    'user' => '',
    'pass' => '',
    'db'   => '',
    'host' => ''
);

require(BASE_DIR.'/lib/dataTables/ssp.class.php');

$result = SSP::simple($_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns);

echo json_encode($result);
```

To use that trick, you also need to edit `ssp.class.php` and replace all instances of `` FROM `$table` `` with `FROM $table` to remove backticks.

Alternatively, there is [github.com/emran/ssp](https://github.com/emran/ssp) repository for library that extends `ssp.class.php` allowing `GROUP BY`, `JOIN`, aliases.

#### LINKS

See [jQuery DataTables: Using WHERE, JOIN and GROUP BY with ssp.class.php](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-using-where-join-and-group-by-with-ssp-class-php/) for more information.

Comment: I had issue to get something working with your code. But I've found a customized SSP class that do the job perfectly. I've updated my post.

Comment: @XavierC., [github.com/emran/ssp](https://github.com/emran/ssp) library could be an alternative, I didn't suggest it because all you need is a simple `JOIN`. I showed sample table structure only, you should replace it with query that fits your DB design.